# Can I add a shortcut to a locally stored file?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, internal-storage, home-screen-shortcuts

I'd like to add a shortcut on Android 4.2.1 to a local pptx file.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Should I delete this trivial question or just accept my  answer (or a better one if one comes) in 2 days ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact it's easy to do using a file explorer application.

I used `ES File Explorer` but I suspect other programs have the same feature.

Using `ES File Explorer`, you have to navigate to the file, then do a long click on the file icon until a menu appears. Then you choose `Shortcut`. Nothing shows the operation works but a new icon will be present in the launcher.

Comment: For explanation purposes of your answer, can you give the steps that you take in ES File Explorer to create the shortcut?

Comment: @RyanConrad Looks like it's just a plain shortcut. I was thinking it was a file shortcut to the homescreen. Don't know if that would be possible, but that's for another question. Haha.

Answer (score 2):

It's a shame that this isn't built into Android. Fortuantely, there are now many apps that can do that (mostly a side functionality of file manager apps).

If you just need a lightweight standalone app for this, I can recommend [File Shortcut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nagopy.file.shortcut&hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

Just adding another file manager alternative to Denys's answer (which really works, +1 for that) which provides a little bit more customization:

[**Total Commander**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander)

1. navigate to the file in Total Commander
2. bring up the context menu by long tapping the file
3. click "*Create link on desktop*"
4. now you can add a **custom text** and optionally a **custom icon** to the shortcut. In the *Command* field, you can also define a **custom command** to run or define a **specific app** you would like to open the file with. (For example if you have a PDF file and multiple PDF viewers (or you have a video file and multiple video players), you can define which the file should open with.)