# add shortcut to a file say a local pdf on to the homescreen

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

My jelly bean phones are not rooted. I was hoping to be able to place a file, or a shortcut to a file, such as a '.pdf' on the homescreen.

I have seen suggestions that it may be done, by using file managers, but maybe that no longer applies. Both devices have 4.2.2 jelly-bean.
See for instance [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39099/can-i-add-a-shortcut-to-a-locally-stored-file).

I have tried on an HTC desire 310 and on an Alcatel onetouch.  I get no option to add the file or shortcut to the home screen. I did install the Astro file manager, with a shortcut on the home screen but did not see any additional option for putting a pdf on the homescreen.

Answer (score 1):

Download and then install the ***latest version*** of [Astro File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro).

long press on a home screen where you want the shortcut. Select **widgets**, then select "Astro". Astro then asks you for choice one file, then you can go to your `pdf Directory` and add it on the home screen. ; )

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same as Mohsen said, with ES File Explorer. Locate the file in the app, and hold on it to select it. At the bottom right, tap More, and then Add to desktop.